# Download service with high or no bandwidth limits

Tags: web-apps, hosted, sharing

I have a popular modpack that I published on the Minecraft platform, Technic Pack.  It has recently boomed to the the top 3 on trending, creating a LOT of downloads.  I have been using my free account on Dropbox for the downloads, but my public links were temporarily banned due to excessive bandwidth usage (over 20GB in one day).  I don't want to pay for a pro account since I make no money off of this modpack, but I still want it to keep on trucking on, so to speak.

So my question is are there other trustworthy download services that I can use for free that have a much higher bandwidth limit or none at all?

Answer (score 1):

I found a site called [x10hosting](https://x10hosting.com), that can be used for downloads.  It has an unlimited download cap, with the only downside being you have to login every month, or they will cancel your account.  I had to figure it out, but to use it for downloads, you have to create a custom website, upload the files, and then when you go to the website, right click the download link and use that as the direct download link.